# Best practices for desktop application credential storage?

Tags: security, desktop-application

I'm developing a desktop app and I want the user to only have to sign in once after install.  How should credentials/tokens be stored?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Credential locker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker) if you're working on a UWP app, and you can find samples to get you started [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PasswordVault)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Windows.Security.Credentials:

```
PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
PasswordCredential credential = null;
try
{
    credential = vault.FindAllByResource("SomeName").FirstOrDefault();
}
catch
{

}
if (credential!=null)
{
    string username = credential.UserName;
    credential.RetrievePassword();
    string password = credential.Password;
}
else
{
    try
    {
        //login
        credential = new PasswordCredential("SomeName",username,password);
        vault.Add(credential);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

U can use the password property as a password or a token.